# Adding multiple ITextSharp binary images using byte array causes IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, itext, html2canvas

I am using **ITextSharp** and **html2canvas** for **adding binary images** and **PDF generation**.

Below is a snippet of my `Codebehind` code.

```
var overallResultsBase64string = hdnOverallResults.Value.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var appServerCapacityBase64string = hdnAppServerCapacity.Value.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var appPerformanceBase64string = hdnAppPerformance.Value.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var dbServerCapacityBase64string = hdnDBServerCapacity.Value.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
var dbPerformanceBase64string = hdnDBPerformance.Value.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

iTextSharp.text.Image overallResultsImg, appServerCapacityImg, appPerformanceImg
  , dbServerCapacityImg, dbPerformanceImg;

byte[] overallResultsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(overallResultsBase64string);
overallResultsImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(overallResultsBytes);
byte[] appServerCapacityBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(appServerCapacityBase64string);
appServerCapacityImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(appServerCapacityBytes);
byte[] appPerformanceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(appPerformanceBase64string);
appPerformanceImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(appPerformanceBytes);
byte[] dbServerCapacityBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dbServerCapacityBase64string);
dbServerCapacityImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dbServerCapacityBytes);
byte[] dbPerformanceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dbPerformanceBase64string);
dbPerformanceImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(dbPerformanceBytes);

document.Add(overallResultsImg);
document.Add(new Paragraph("OVERALL APPLICATION PERFORMANCE"));
document.Add(appPerformanceImg);
document.Add(dbPerformanceImg);
document.Add(new Paragraph("OVERALL SERVER CAPACITY"));
document.Add(appServerCapacityImg);
document.Add(dbServerCapacityImg);
```

`var appServerCapacityBase64string` is `NULL` that it throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception on

```
byte[] appServerCapacityBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(appServerCapacityBase64string);
appServerCapacityImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(appServerCapacityBytes);
```

Is there something wrong with my **Javascript html2canvas** code below? Kindly check.

```
<script>
   html2canvas($("#overallResultsDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById("hdnOverallResults").value = myImage;
        }
    });

    html2canvas($("#appServerCapacityDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
           $("#hdnAppServerCapacity").value = myImage;
        }
    });

    html2canvas($("#appPerformanceDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById("hdnAppPerformance").value = myImage;
        }
    });

    html2canvas($("#dbServerCapacityDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById("hdnDBServerCapacity").value = myImage;
        }
    });

    html2canvas($("#dbPerformanceDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById("hdnDBPerformance").value = myImage;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**ONLY** the **first html2canvas** **successfully** passes the `base64 string` to the respective `HiddenField` as value and is **successfully** accessed in `CodeBehind`. What is wrong with my script that makes the `5 HiddenFields` return **NULL**?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing  `var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` to different names in your functions?